# ssh network is unreachable but it is from another pc

Tags: ssh, networking

I created an adhoc wifi network and connected to it using my windows desktop and chrome laptop. Both are on the network and I can ping my laptop from my desktop. I can connect via scp and ssh on my desktop. However on my chrome I get

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.0 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

Obviously that's a lie if we're both connected to the same adhoc network and I can ssh into 10.0.0.0. So what's going on? There is a many second delay before I can connect with ssh

Comment: is this a home network or a work network?

Comment: You'll need to clarify your network architecture to begin with if you want any chance in someone pinpointing where the issue lies.  Which machine is at 10.0.0.0 and is it reachable with `ping`?

Comment: And a quick note, computers don't lie.  Their program simply express what they were programmed to say in specific conditions and there are many reasons `ssh` on that computer could consider the connection unreachable.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: I'm using a laptop (chrome+galliumos), a desktop (windows7) and a pi. I believe I fixed it. I changed the IP address so its sitting on 10.0.0.**1**, galliumos has issues connecting to it but chrome OS (same laptop, its a duel boot) and kali (vm on desktop) have no issues connecting to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.0.0.0 is the first IP of a subnet regardless of how it is subnetted as it is the VERY first IP of the private 10 space.  That is a network ID and should not be used as the IP of a host.  The last IP of a subnet is a broadcast address.  This one is dependent of the network ID and the subnet mask.  If this is how you have an IP set, you need to change it.

Comment: Why should there be no host as the network IP? The host in question is running the network/broadcasting the access point